# Cannot paste image in Skype, Line, or Facebook Messenger but pasting works in WeChat and iMessage

Tags: ios, messages, copy-paste

In iOS 7, we're able to paste an image into iMessage, WeChat, and Whatsapp, but not Line, Skype, or Facebook Messenger.
Is this an app-supported setting?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting in images into the app requires support from the app's developer to allow this. This isn't as simple as a setting and therefore can't be adjusted externally.